# Selector Modes in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3

I just installed Flash Builder 4.7 (Trial version),Suddenly I lost Source and Design Mode.It is strange,because in first day I had both.I checked everything but It doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FlashBuilder 4.7 hasn't got the design view anymore. Only the source view, which you are seeing!
4.6 still has it. Maybe you upgraded in trial.